# Measure real object from image

Tags: image, image-processing, artificial-intelligence

I am going to prepare my assignment. It's a bit freaky as our Teacher, though :D. Okay, the job is simple. There will be a white cloth vertically. A person will be in front of that. Distance of the man from the cloth is 3 feet. The shadow of the person will be caught through a mid res (say 1600 X 1200) camera. The image (img01.jpg) of this camera is my input. I have to measure the man's body from the image, I mean parts of body. I need 80 to 90 percent accuracy. Desired output is some length (centimeter):

A = ?

B = ?

C = ?

D = ?

E = ?

Just as the picture:

[image]

I don't know what type of algorithm is needed here and I don't want to ask it to my freaky Sir. Great hearts here are requested to help me. Do not ask me for my code as I don't have yet. I don't need codes rather I need algorithms to do the job.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We need more context. Since you mentioned a "teacher", what type of course is this? What are the most recent topics you have dicussed? Can you use a neural network?

Comment: This is our OOP2 course. I got it on lottery. We discussed simple image editing like drawing shapes, strings on image. [Dont know why some people vote it down :(]

Comment: Adding the c# and winforms tags is really pointless, don't you think so ? Also, your problem is not really measuring A, B, C, etc. Your problem is getting to an image that resembles your picture.

Comment: I believe you are still missing the main point, the question you are asking here is trivial in comparison to obtaining your sample input.

Answer (score 2):

Find the number of pixels between the points and multiply by the number of cm's per pixel based on how far the subject is from the camera.

Comment: Any library reference to find the number of pixels from one point to another?

Answer (score 2):

A possible algorithm would be, given a vertical offset `y`, to find the distance (in pixels) between the first colored (or in your case, black) pixel and the last one, on the same line `y`. Then, you can use your unit conversion as you deem convenient, once you fix the scale between pixels and your real world measure. This answer would work assuming, as in your example, that the distance is measured horizontally and not diagonally on the figure.